# Create Thumbnail from url like Digg in asp.net/C#

Tags: asp.net, facebook, thumbnails, digg

How I can create a thumbnail from a URL?

For example:

- Like on Digg, when I submit a link, Digg choses a Thumbnail from any images on that URL.
- Or like Facebook, when I submit a link, I can chose a thumbnail for that link.

So, how I can do that with ASP.Net/C#.  I just want to create a thumbnail (not a screenshot of the web page).

Answer (score 0):

To create a screenshot from a web page you need to have an interface to a layout engine like **Gecko** or **Webkit**. You may use **khtml2png** for creating web page screenshots.

To create thumbnails from the web page you have to parse the web page's source, download the image links and resize them to the given thumbnail size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [C# wrapper for CutyCapt](http://nolovelust.com/post/C-Website-Screenshot-Generator-AKA-Get-Screenshot-of-Webpage-With-Aspnet-C.aspx).

Comment: Thanks in no small part to your work, nLL, I have blogged about a similar system here: http://www.roastedamoeba.com/blog/archive/2010/11/04/creating-website-thumbnail-images-in-aspnet.